# Error is index exceeds matrix dimensions while find canny edges of a grayscale image

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide, matlab-deployment

I need your help.I am a started in OCR & text Detection.I am trying to extract the text from natural images i just start working on it. i am using following technique for edge detection.

```
i=imread('handicapped.jpg');
gray=rgb2gray(i);
imshow(gray);
edge=edge(gray,'canny',0.3);
imshow(edge);
```

but i have an error in line four while

```
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in test11 (line 4)
edge=edge(gray,'canny',0.3);
```

Help towards MATLAB soruce code in this field is also appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You use a name of a function for a variable... In the same line! :/

Comment: I am totally new in this field. please tell me which technique should i use? and u find me its source code ? i want to learn via the source code. Adiel

Comment: Never use a name of a function as a name of a variable. In your code change the name of the variable in the line of error like that: `edgeImg=edge(gary,'canny',0.3); imshow(edgeImg);`

Comment: Thank you so much its working. please help me in text detection from images which technique should i use?